# Goals conceded from corners in the English Premier League in season 2012/13

Tags: football, trivia, records, english-premier-league

In the 2012-13 season of the English Premier League:

- How many goals were conceded from corners?
- Which team conceded the most from corners?
- Which team conceded the least from corners?

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this link](http://www.statsbomb.com/2013/08/corners-goals-for-goals-conceded-from-corners-premier-league/) offers the information you're after. Assuming it's correct:

How many goals were conceded from corners: 126

Which team conceded the most from corners: QPR (10)

Which team conceded the least from corners: Chelsea/Norwich (3)

Comment: Where does the source data come from?

Comment: @MichaelMyers - Second this. Looking through their site, they don't give any mention about their data source really (from what I could see). It's a pretty bare site in terms of amount of content which makes it more questionable.